# Using Bloomberg API on Excel to find a stock ticker change/acquisition

Tags: bloomberg

I am wondering if there is a way in Excel, using Bloomberg API, to find if tickers have changed or acquired by other firms.

For example, given these values,

```
BOFI US (Axos Financial Inc)
EVHC US (Envision Healthcare Corp)
COOL US (PolarityTE Inc)
```

it should return

```
AX US (ticker change on 2018/10/01)
Acquired by KKR on 2018/10/11
PTE US (ticker change on 2018/09/18)
```

respectively.

Comment: BDP("BOFI  EQUITY","EQY_PRIM_SECURITY_TICKER") = 'AX'

Comment: @hjw I found that BDP("BOFI EQUITY", "MARKET_STATUS") gives me a solution that I wanted. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, asking for `MARKET_STATUS`
may not be enough, because Bloomberg is reusing
tickers. For instance, suppose you have a list of
equity tickers that you had in a portfolio some years
ago. A stock may have become delisted, but its ticker
may subsequently have been given to another stock.
In such cases, you may want to check `HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME` as well.

An example, for which I use R; but you can use the same
fields in Excel.

```
library("Rblpapi")
blpConnect()

ticker <- "DRIV US Equity"
bdp(ticker, c("NAME", "MARKET_STATUS"))
##                                        NAME MARKET_STATUS
## DRIV US Equity GLOBAL X AUTONOMOUS&ELEC-ETF          ACTV
```

But five years ago, that ticker belonged to a different
company.

```
bdp(ticker,
    "HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME",
    overrides = c(HISTORICAL_ID_TM_RANGE_START_DT = "20130101"))
##                HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME
## DRIV US Equity              1611364D US

bdp("1611364D US Equity", c("NAME", "MARKET_STATUS"))
##                                 NAME MARKET_STATUS
## 1611364D US Equity DIGITAL RIVER INC          ACQU
```