# Bloomberg API / Excel Add In - Delisted Stocks

Tags: equities, data, bloomberg, excel, fundamentals

So I am using the Bloomberg Excel add in but can also use the API. My dilemma is I have a list of tickers containing SP500 historical constituents and I have retrieved 600 of them from an alternative source who supply fundamental data such as revenue.

However, for the delisted ones Bloomberg seems the only place that holds fundamentals for delisted tickers, but the problem is how do I feed it the tickers I am looking for, firstly the tickers are structured as so 'PBG-201002' so ticker and year it delisted.

But Bloomberg doesn't understand this so I am wondering how I can translate this into Bloomberg, fairly new to it too so any help will go a long way. :)

Comment: What is pbg? I doubt you will get that directly with the API. As much as I know BBG does not have a ticker syntax where you have a year of delisting. If you have the isin, or similar identifiers you can use that directly. BBG has 24/7 support and should be way better equipped to answer this.in terms of excel and API, there is no difference (apart from some things that only work in Excel) as it's all based on the same c** api.

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42264/using-bloomberg-api-on-excel-to-find-a-stock-ticker-change-acquisition/42353#42353

Comment: @AKdemy PBG is just an example, so for instance 'PBG US Equity' would return the latest company using that ticker. However, say a company 10 years ago used this ticker, I want to be able to find and extract their data. But after speaking with Bloomberg they had told me that once a ticker is re-used their system generates a random number that is assigned to the ticker, so it goes from once being 'PBG US Equity' to something like '27800987 US'

Comment: @EnricoSchumann This looks like something I could definitely work with, rather than searching each company name one by one on the terminal

Comment: @EnricoSchumann I know that's in R and I only know Python, but is the general gist of it that you input the ticker and a date of when it would of been listed under that ticker and it should return the Bloombergs randomly generated new ticker for it?

Comment: Yes, if the ticker has been reused. The fundamental/price data should then be attached to the returned ticker.

Comment: Great, thankyou very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of Enrico definitely works. The APIs are all the same (R is actually not a BBG solution but someone made the C++ API - which is also what excel is based on - usable within R).

`=BDP("DRIV US Equity","HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME","HISTORICAL_ID_TM_RANGE_START_DT = 20130101")` for the excel equivalent. Python uses the same overrides (BLPAPI) as found on `WAPI`.

If you had the ISIN, you could easily just use that (or BBG FIGI `"ID_BB_Global"` but this is less likely to get). `=BDP("US25388B1044 Isin","Ticker")` for example which is the ISIN for the "old" DRIV US which shows the "new" ticker 161136D. You do not need the ticker, and can get the fundamental data directly via the ISIN.

You can also look it up [online](https://www.openfigi.com/search#!?simpleSearchString=driv%20us&page=1) where you can enter a FIGI, ticker, company name, other identifier.

Comment: Great thankyou. This is a much easier way than searching each company name on a terminal. I saw that you could use ISIN, CUSIP and others as the input but sadly could not find somewhere which had these available. I did look at FIGI but it returns hundreds of results for a ticker so didn't know which ID to use. Do you know in Excel how I could use that formula as a drag/drop, as I have a list of tickers 'AM US Equity' in a column and then the dates in another '20120801' and was wondering if I could use the formula as a somewhat function. Sadly I do not have Python on this terminal either

Comment: Something like: ```=BDP("C2","HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME","HISTORICAL_ID_TM_RANGE_START_DT = D2")``` Whereby C2 and D2 are Excel cells. As I have 400 tickers to do

Comment: =BDP(C2,"HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME","HISTORICAL_ID_TM_RANGE_START_DT",TEXT(D2,"YYYYMMDD")) as the override needs to have the specific format. YYYYMMDD is language specific, would be JJJJMMTT in German for instance.

Comment: Legend, thanks!

Comment: It worked, didn't seem to like the last part of the formula, but worked with just ```"=BDP(C2,"HISTORICAL_ID_POINT_TIME","HISTORICAL_ID_TM_RANGE_START_DT",D2)"```

Comment: Do you know how I would then be able to use these tickers I extracted to find out what exchange they were listed on? I have tried a few fields such as EXCH_CODE and others however the best I have got so far is just the country of the exchange, so 'US' for instance, but what I want really is 'NASDAQ' etc

Comment: Pretty sure F1 F1 (help desk) will answer that within a few minutes. I do not think Bloomberg stores any of this. All fields like DS395 "LISTED_EXCH_OF_COMPOSITE" are current value only and blank for delisted / inactive tickers. The US you mention is the ticker exchange code for the composite (not directly related to the country).  You can find the primary exchange for expired: =BDP("1611364D US Equity","ORIG_PRIM_EXCH_CODE") which is UW and =BDP("1611364D US Equity","ORIG_PRIM_EXCH_NAME") which shows that UW is NASDAQ GS. That all does not matter for fundamental data though.